# My variable is not changing from true to false, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, variables

I am making a box able to cycle through 2 colors, but none of the variables are changing.
All variables are defined and red1 = true and green1 = false.
red and green are variables with the hex code of that color.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", skins)

function skins(e) {
    if (e.key == "w"){
        if (red1) {
            green1 = true;
            color = green;
            red1 = false;
        }
    }
    if (green1) {
        red1 = true;
        color = red;
        green1 = false;
    }
}
```

When I open it, the box is red, but when I press w nothing happens, when I check the console none of the variables have changed. I have tried putting an alert in the if(red1) and it worked.

Comment: how are you changing the colors in the css if you are planning to do that? Also is green and red variables?

Comment: After changing green1 to true, the last if statement is executed and it reverses the changes.

Comment: Are those variables global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var input = document.getElementById("btn");

input.addEventListener("keydown", skins)
 var red1 = true;
 var  color = "red";
 var  green1 = false;
 
function skins(e) {
    if (e.key == "w"){
        if (red1) {
            green1 = true;
            color = "green";
            red1 = false;
        }
     else if (green1) {
        red1 = true;
        color = "red";
        green1 = false;
      }
    }
   console.log(color);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="btn">type w</input>
```

If you want values to be changed only when key "w" is pressed. then try the following code. if not, please let me know the scenario.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", skins)

function skins(e) {
    if (e.key == "w"){
        if (red1) {
            green1 = true;
            color = green;
            red1 = false;
        }
     else if (green1) {
        red1 = true;
        color = red;
        green1 = false;
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a bit of scope issues. Right now red1 and green1 are not defined in your example. If the values are undefined you will not be able to trigger the conditional statements. But for simplicity sake let’s assume you have defined red1 as true and green1 as false earlier in your code. If the user presses the w key, the code will hit the first conditional and switch red1 to false and green1 to true. (I am ignoring color variable at this point.)

The code then continues to the next conditional and now green1 is true so it sets red1 back to true and green1 back to false. You might want to consider adding return after the red1 true conditional. The return exits the function, preventing it from reaching the next conditional.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", skins)

function skins(e) {
    if (e.key == "w"){
        if (red1) {
            green1 = true;
            color = green;
            red1 = false;
            return;
        }
    }
    if (green1) {
        red1 = true;
        color = red;
        green1 = false;
    }
}
```